# org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of Android

Tags: android, json, web-services

I am trying to retrieve values from JSON and I am getting responseString as empty. Here is my code

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpContext httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);
String jsons = "";
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("tbl_id", tableid);
jsonObject.put("imei_no", phneimeino);
jsonObject.put("server_id", usrid);
jsonObject.put("customers", customerName1 + "," + customerName2 + "," + customerName3);
Log.w("JSON OBJECT is ", jsonObject.toString());
jsons = jsonObject.toString();
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jsons);
httpPost.setEntity(se);
httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, httpContext);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
Log.i("Response", responseString);
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseString);
success = json.getString("iserror");
```

Here responseString is empty and showing the exception as

```
org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
```

Comment: response service method is get or post method? check it your service.

Comment: Print your `responseString` and check if it is valid json

Comment: I Printed responseString but it's blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably getting a blank response. Its not null but the response is empty. So you are getting this error and not a Nullpointer exception.

Check with your backend developer

Comment: Problem with Backend(CMS) Side

Answer (score 1):

responseString is blank,so you can't:
      success = json.getString("iserror");
check your httpPost and service